# iPhone Camera pictures from UIImagePickerController are sideways

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, camera, uiimagepickercontroller, image

My application supports taking pictures from iPhone in portrait mode and upload to the server.

However, the pictures taken are appearing in sideways once uploaded to the server.

Please help!

-KC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Images captured used AV Foundation (at least using AVCapture, which I'm using) are taken in landscape mode, so you have to rotate them clockwise before sending to the server.

Comment: how do you do that (swift)

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that the image has an associated `imageOrientation` property that will determine the correct orientation to display the image.